# how I can tell if a filename contains two or more dots eg. 45FGG.TESTDOC.MAY12.png ,carimage.30.jpg so how to store this image with its extension

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3

I'm looking to find out how I can tell if a filename contains two or more dots.

> eg. 45FGG.TESTDOC.MAY12.png, carimage.30.jpg.

So, how to store this image with its extension?

Comment: You can always look up regex or you can check to see if the indexOf and lastIndexOf are equal to one another meaning there is only 1 or none.

Comment: Do you care? Search backward for the dot? `strrch()`

Comment: You might also try splfileinfo https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getextension.php

Answer (score 1):

You can easily count the dots with regex:

PHP

```php
preg_match_all("/\./", "45FGG.TESTDOC.MAY12.png"); // 3
```

JS

```
"45FGG.TESTDOC.MAY12.png".match(/\./g).length; // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here are two test cases:**

```
$file1 = "hello.jpg";
$file2 = "hello.file.jpg";

echo "\$file1: " . $file1 . "\n";
echo "\$file2: " . $file2 . "\n\n";

echo "Position of \$file1's first '.' : " . strpos($file1, '.') . "\n";
echo "Position of \$file1's last  '.' : " . strripos($file1, '.') . "\n";
echo "Position of \$file2's first '.' : " . strpos($file2, '.') . "\n";
echo "Position of \$file2's last  '.' : " . strripos($file2, '.') . "\n\n";

if (strpos($file1, '.') != strripos($file1, '.'))
{
    echo "\$file1 has >= 2 dots\n";
}
else
{
    echo "\$file1 has 1 dot \n";
}
if (strpos($file2, '.') != strripos($file2, '.'))
{
    echo "\$file2 has >= 2 dots\n";
}
else
{
    echo "\$file2 has 1 dot \n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
$file1: hello.jpg
$file2: hello.file.jpg

Position of $file1's first '.' : 5
Position of $file1's last  '.' : 5
Position of $file2's first '.' : 5
Position of $file2's last  '.' : 10

$file1 has 1 dot
$file2 has >= 2 dots
```